# Svelte / Typescript - sharing a namespace across multiple files

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm not sure if it's possible, but before I rule it out, I just wanted some feedback.

I am organising the variable types in my Svelte/Typescript project under namespaces.  I would ideally like all types from multiple files organised under a single namespace (Types)

For example:
**- /types/type.user.ts**

```
export namespace Types {
  export type User {
   name : '',
   email: ''
  }
}
```

And then in **-components/type.column.ts**

```
export namespace Types {
  export type Column {
   id : '',
   filter : ''
  }
}
```

The problem arises when importing these type into a single file as it causes an ambiguity in resolving the export namespace:

```
import { Type } from "/src/types/type.user";
import { Type } from "/src/components/types/type.column";
```

I can't see a way to work around this.  Is this possible before I resign myself to giving up  on namespaces or merging types into a single file?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#multi-file-namespaces

Comment: @Jhecht thanks, already referenced that guide before posting the question.  I could not get it to work in svelte unfortunately.

Comment: are you using the `/// <reference path="./components/type.column.ts />` and `<reference path="./types/type.user.ts" />` as well as using the reference? I built a quick deno project and nothing seems amiss but I can verify with some svelte

Comment: Yes, I tries using the references but they don't seem to have an effect in Svelte.  Did you get it working in Svelte?

Comment: checking now, give me like 5 minutes to make a new svelte project

Comment: got something working, lot of text to include so I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work I created 3 files: `src/components/type.column.ts`, `src/types/type.user.ts` and `component.svelte`.

I also had to modify the tsconfig.json file by setting `"isoluatedModules": false` (as that is apparently the default for svelte projects created with Vite).

#### src/components/type.column.ts

```
namespace Types {
  export type Column = {
    id: string;
    filter: string;
  }
}
```

#### src/types/type.user.ts

```
/// <reference path="../components/type.column.ts" />
namespace Types {
  export type User = { 
    name: string;
    email: string;
  }
}
```

#### component.svelte

```html
<script lang="ts">
/// <reference path="../types/type.user.ts">
const someUser: Types.User = {
  email: '',
  name: ''
};

const someColumn: Types.Column = {
  filter: '',
  id: 'some-id'
};

</script>
```

I will note, however, that I'm not sure I would personally use this method. I tend to try and keep things in the most related location, so I would likely just remove the `Types` namespace, and simply export the singular type from each file. I don't see an issue with doing something like:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import type { User } from '../types/type.user';
import type { Column } from '../components/type.column';
const someuser: User = {...};
const someColumn: Column = {...};
</script>
```

This largely boils down to personal preference, but by changing the `isolatedModules` setting it's possible we would run into errors with svelte preprocessor later down the line -- I'll be forward in saying I don't actually know a lot about the svelte team's reasoning for using this setting so I can't speak too much more about it, but I figure they must have put it there for a reason. Just keep in mind that while this works, it may end up being the cause of some frustrations in the future.

Comment: I came to pretty much the same solution as yours.  Although, I could not export the singular types as you suggested as it causes errors in the IDE.   By removing export namespace from namespace, I get it to work.  Strangely, I do not even need to import the types file in my main svelte file.  Another issues is that Webstorm and VS code  both complain the namespace should be exported.   Not sure if I should supress the error.  As you have warned me, it could cause problems in the future.  I'll need to think about which route to go down.  Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: What errors does exporting the singular type cause in your IDE? I use VSCode and mine didn't complain; wondering if that's something specific to webstorm?

Comment: If I don't export the namespace (namespace Types) instead of (export namespace Types) both VsCode and Webstorm produce the error "TS1208: 'type.column.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file"

Comment: ah I see. I was more tired than I thought when I read your reply. Apologies.